# Group having elements of order 2,3,5 and 6 but not 15 or 10

Tags: group-theory

$S_5$ satisfies this requirement and the question in my notes is whether there are any groups not-isomorphic to it which also satisfy it. I can't seem to figure it out, would greatly appreciate if someone could elucidate the general principles behind this kind of exercise.

Comment: Is there a condition on the size of the group?  Otherwise, something of the form $S_5\times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ should work, where $p$ is a prime other than $2$ and $3$.

Comment: No restriction, but I don't quite see why your answer works. For p = 5 we don't have elements of order 6, no?

Comment: Of course, the element $(\pi,1))\in S_5\times C_7$ has order $6$, where $\pi\in S_5$ has order $6$. For example, $\pi=(123)(45)$.

Comment: @othi Rather, $p=5$ gives us elements of order $15$ and $10$, so $p$ hsould not be $5$, either

Comment: If $H$ is any group of order prime to 30 then $S_5\times H$ will work.

Comment: There are also such groups that are in no way related to $S_5$, for example $C_6*C_5$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $C_6 *C_5$ has an element of order 15 no?

Comment: Also, suppose I take p =7, then I don't have order 6 anymore right? Because $lcm\{6,7}\ = 42$

Comment: othi, no. In one factor we can take the identity element $1$, which has order $1$.

Comment: If we stick to finite groups then there is a split extension of $\mathbb{Z}_5\times \mathbb{Z}_5$ by an element of order $6$ acting fixed-point-freely.

Comment: @othi there are elements of order 6 in $S_5$ itself.

Comment: @DietrichBurde of course! Thanks! Can we say in general that the order of elements in direct product is given by lcm of order of any two elements? Does that exhaust everything?

Comment: Never mind, of course it does. Thanks!

Comment: Can Sylow groups results help ?

Comment: @othi $*$ is the *free* product, not the direct product. It is not unlikely that you haven't heard about it yet.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen indeed I have not. Apologies!

Comment: @othi You're right, I missed $p=5$ in my list.  You should avoid that prime too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several finite groups different from $S_5$ also having elements of order $1,2,3,5,6$, but not of oder $10,15$, for example all direct products $S_5\times H$ with a finite group $H$ whose order is not divisible by $2,3,5$.

It even seems to be wrong that
$S_5$ is the unique finite group, up to isomorphism, having elements of order $1,2,3,5,6$ and of *no other order*, see the comment below.

Edit: Let $\pi_e(G)$ denote the set of orders of elements in $G$. For finite simple (nonabelian) groups $G$ and an arbitrary group $H$ there was the conjecture that if $G$ and $H$ have the same order and $\pi_e(G)=\pi_e(H)$, then $G\cong H$. However, even here counterexamples where found, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.03786).

Comment: And I don't believe it anyway: what about my example $\mathbb{Z}_6$ acting fpf on $V_2(\mathbb{F}_5)$ in the comments?

Comment: Yes, I have edited it. So is this group $(C_5\times C_5) \rtimes C_6$?

Comment: You can also define an infinite family of such examples  as $C_5^{2k} \rtimes C_6$, where the action of $C_6$ on each $C_5^2$ is the same (thereby maging $C_5^{2k}$ into a homogeneous module for $C_6$).

Comment: I think in the conjecture that is disproved in the linked paper, the hypothesis is that $G$ is simple and $H$ is an arbitrary finite group of order $|G|$ with $\pi_e(G) = \pi_e(H)$. (It would be true if we assumed that both $G$ and $H$ were simple.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, of course. Thank you.